# Unclear about driver.getWindowHandles() & driver.getWindowHandle()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi all I am learning Selenium & I am not really clear about how the above two functions work:
Problem Statement:

I have a practice assignment say: Go to http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/

Click on a link> Multiple Windows A Window opens> Click on>> Click Here Another Window opens>> from this window grab text and print it After that go back to this http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows and print text.

Flow: [http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/>>>http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows>>>http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows/new](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/%3E%3E%3Ehttp://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows%3E%3E%3Ehttp://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows/new)

Que1) If I use driver.getWindowHandle() and print it for each window its value remains constant so does this method always returns the parent window or it works differently.

Ques2) When I use driver.getWindowHandles() it is returning 2 values in the set. Does driver.getWindowHandles() return the parent window as well. (I am not sure if there should be 2 or 3 values as I have 3 URLS I thought the set should have 3)

Ques3) Can someone share the most effective way to work with multiple child window id's:

> Set with iterator method
> People also convert Set to Arraylist and then use get method. [which is a better way]

Code:

```
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        String p1=driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println(p1);
        text1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/windows']"));
        text1.click();
        WebElement 
        text2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/windows/new']"));
        text2.click();
        Set<String> child=driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println(child.size());
        ArrayList<String> children=new ArrayList<String>(child);
        System.out.println(children);
        driver.switchTo().window(children.get(1));
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/h3")).getText());
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(children.get(0));
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/h3")).getText());
        driver.switchTo().window("");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.close();
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that code would compile because of the line that has `WebElement` -- may I assume you have that fixed when you are running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
            String p1=driver.getWindowHandle(); //Gets the newly opened and the only window handle

            System.out.println("This is parent window handle " + p1);
            text1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/windows']"));
            text1.click(); //Navigates, no new window opened. Handle remains the same

            //WebElement 'Unnecessary code

            text2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/windows/new']"));
            text2.click(); //opens second window/tab as per the settings. there are 2 window handles here for current driver instance
            Set<String> child=driver.getWindowHandles(); //set of 2
            System.out.println(child.size());
    //          ArrayList<String> children=new ArrayList<String>(child);' modifying this
            
             String strSecondWindowHandle = "";
             for(String str : s) // as set is not an ordered collection we need to loop through it to know which position holds which handle. 
            {
                if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(p1) == false) //to check if the window handle is not equal to parent window handle
                {
                         driver.switchTo().window(str) // this is how you switch to second window
                         strSecondWindowHandle = str;
                         break;
                }
            }
//            System.out.println(children);
//            driver.switchTo().window(children.get(1)); //not required
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/h3")).getText());
            driver.close(); // now this will close the second window
            driver.switchTo().window(p1); // switches to main window
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/h3")).getText());
//            driver.switchTo().window(""); //not required as it is the same window
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.close(); //closes the main window
```

So to answer your questions

Window handle is automatically and uniquely assigned by the operating system (Windows) to each newly opened window

**Q1** --> Until and unless you explicityly switch the windows, the window handle remains the same. switching is the key here.

**Q2** --> Navigating does not change the handles. it is not page specific rather it is window specific. getWindowHandles will return all the open browser windows opened by WebDriver instances that is currently running. Already open windows are not included.

**Q3** --> Using the for loop demonstrated above, you open the window, find the ID which is not your parent window handle, store it in a variable. Repeat the procedure for more windows.

Comment: Thankyou @Mithilesh Indurkar for the explanation. This was v helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) what are the main differences between `getWindowHandle()` and `getWindowHandles()` methods:

`getWindowHandle()`: Return an opaque handle to this window that uniquely identifies it within this driver instance.

`getWindowHandles()`: Return a set of window handles which can be used to iterate over all open windows of this WebDriver instance by passing them to `switchTo().WebDriver.Options.window()`

In simpler terms, `driver.getWindowHandles()` stores the set of handles for all the pages opened simultaneously, but `driver.getWindowHandle()` fetches the handle of the web page which is in focus. It gets the address of the active browser and it has a return type of String.